# Implementation of GoogleAPi Authentication

Tags: groovy, google-api, openid, connect, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to implement the OpenID authentication for Google APIs, according to [Google documentation](http://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login?hl=es):

I'm having trouble in the second step when sending the authentication request to Google. In the response I'm not receiving the code that Google is supposed to send me. This is my code:

```
def client = new RESTClient("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth")

def p   = [
                scope:  scope,
                state: "security_token="+state,
                redirect_uri:   redirecturi,
                response_type:  responsetype,
                client_id:      clientID,       
                ignoreSSLIssues: true,                  
            ]

def response =  client.post ( body : p,
                            contentType : URLENC)
```

I made sure all of the parameters are correct, but in the response I'm getting `Status 302` and I'm not receiving the code.

I'm only having doubts with the `redirect_uri`, I'm using this one:

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server can't make an HTTP request to that URL, it needs to be opened in the browser by the user who will be authenticating. Be sure to read through the [authentication docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2).

Comment: Is there a way to skip the " user consent" part, I need to implement a script where I can get the code, the token and then call the Google Calendar Api, but it has to be transparent for the user. is there another URL that I can use for that purpose?

Comment: You can not skip user consent. If you have a single account you want to use for all users you can manually consent once and then hard code the offline credentials.